# AlpineJS bind no-value attribute

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I tried toggle the "open" attribute with alpine

```
<div class="..." x-bind:open="openCondition"></div>
```

but this lead to the result that "open" always be bound

```
<div class="..." open="true"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="..." open="false"></div>
```

Is there any way that I can achieve binding "open" with no value like the result below:

```
<div class="..." open></div>
```

Comment: Currently, if to look at the [Alpine source code](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/main/packages/alpinejs/src/utils/bind.js#L85), the boolean attributes, including `open`, can be set only in the form `open="open"` or not set at all. There are no such variations like `open="true"` or `open="false"`.

Comment: This save my day.
Struggling with this problem for whole day long.
Should have read the code sooner.